# Mac OS X on OpenStack

Tags: macos, kvm, openstack

Has anyone got a Mac VM working on OpenStack?  It is possible on KVM with a patch so the theory is there http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~somlo/OSXKVM/ but has anyone done it and how maintainable is it?

Comment: My understanding is this would be in violation of Mac TOS, and therefore illegal.

Comment: @MattJoyce my understanding is that it is expressly permitted on Apple hardware; which is backed up by VMWare's knowledge base [article on the subject](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1000131).

Comment: Is anyone running openstack on apple hardware?  I mean...  I assume you'd have to work with a linux on top of the apple gear.  But as long as you had the hardware support then... It should work.

Comment: It's easier to start with [virtualbox](http://virtualbox.org/) where it allows you host a virtual machine with OS X. notice this is just virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

I would try virtualbox first. Here is a guide:
http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/05/os-x-mavericks-in-virtualbox-with-niresh.html

Answer (score 0):

Vmware patches from my experience are most compatible but after looking over what is described in the post, I'd say it looks solid. Honestly, even though it should work, expect a different set of issues with KVM compared to native.